# Does the position property override the display property?

Tags: css

When you use any `position` property other than static or relative, does it override the `display` property (except none)?

It would seem that you cannot have `display: inline; position: absolute;`

Does changing the `position` property alter also set the `display` property to inline-block?

I tried setting an element display to inline and looking in my Chrome developer tools to see if it was overridden but it doesn't appear to be. Essentially, does CSS just "view" the element as inline-block now?

Comment: `position: absolute` overrides any `display` property

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand how it works so I can understand expected behaviour. Is there documentation that I would find answers to questions like these? (I couldn't find the answer on mozilla.org). Or some kind of "source-y-like" code to determine expected behaviour? (the better I understand it, the better my websites will be)

Comment: Here's a good link: https://bitsofco.de/how-positioning-css-properties-interact/

Comment: Thank you. I will devour the article ;). If anyone is aware of documentation that is deeper than w3 or Mozilla, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @JeffVdovjak CSS2.1 Chapter 9.7 is very useful in this case. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Thanks @sanriot I didn't think to look at w3.org (I was trying to find the answer at w3schools.com)

Comment: @sanriot - It is indeed, but a bit outdated. display types `contents` `flow-root`, `flex`, `inline-flex`, `grid` and `inline-grid` aren't covered there.

Comment: @Alohci That's right. But I think this section is most useful because those `display` value (`grid`, `flex`, etc.) is defined in respective modules, and it is complicated to explain them all.